# How to pass model data in to generate razor view

Tags: asp.net-web-api, razor

I am trying to figure out how I can pass model data from a controller to a razor view in a non-mvc Razor Pages web application.

We have a system in process where we currently generate a model, and send it off to an external service which will bind a razor template with the model and send an email.  We need to migrate away from the external service and switch over to our existing mail service.  I already have the model ready to post to an endpoint, and I have the code that will send an email with the html body.  All the examples I have seen for Razor Pages either generate the model in the cshtml.cs file.  I can create a web app that has a controller with an endpoint where I can post the json model (which I deserialize to a custom class), and I have razor pages that can bind to my custom class.  I just can't figure out how I can go from the controller that receives the request, to passing that data to the Razor page to render the view.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, after hours of searching I posted this and was presented with a "Does this answer your question" suggestion before posting.  I was "No, that is not it."  After posting and re-reading, yeah, that was it. :(

Answer here:
[How pass objects from one page to another on ASP.Net Core with razor pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772632/how-pass-objects-from-one-page-to-another-on-asp-net-core-with-razor-pages?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I was using routeValues, but that can only have simple types. I can't pass my custom class. I could serialize it, but that seems like a hack.  Is there a way to do this?