# How do return Page with a model in ASP.Net Core Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

How to I Redirect to a Page and Passing its model?
Just like what we have in MVC 
`return View(model: MyModel);`

What i have tried: 
 `return RedirectToPage("/Notify", new { Model = notifierVM });`

[image]

**Note: the Page I want to return has no PageModel behind**

Comment: Check this out - it's about using DI service to set data on one page and load on other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772632/how-pass-objects-from-one-page-to-another-on-asp-net-core-with-razor-pages

Answer (score 2):

MVC has built in dictionary object **TempData**.
You can serialize your model, put JSON string into TempData and then on the redirected action you can get and deserialize JSON string into object.

```
public ActionResult Create(Booking item)
{
    TempData["data"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyModel);
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = 1 });
}
```

On other action

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    object o;
    TempData.TryGetValue("data", out o);
    var MyModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your sample is in MVC pattern. Am asking about Razor Pages

Comment: @Nellymandela you can use TempData in Razor Pages too: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tempdata

Comment: @MikeBrind is that the best practice?

Comment: There's a warning to not store complex types in the TempData

Comment: Using TempData is fine for passing complex objects. You just need to  take care of serialisation/deserialisation your self. The alternative is to pass a simple value indicating the status of the operation to the redirect page and then construct the model there.