# return View(model: MyModel); equivalent in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I expected to see something like `return Page(model: MyModel);` in ASP Razor Pages. instead the Page(); has no parameter.

So I can return Pages which does not have PageModel class.

I cant use TempData as MyModel is a complex type.

How do I get the same functionality we have with ASP MVC `return View(model: MyModel);`

Please, The question is not for all MVC developers but experienced ASP.Net Core Razor Page developers.
Thank you.

Comment: you sould return a object  that define in the function other wise {model: MyModel}

Comment: This question is essentially identical to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207419/how-do-return-page-with-a-model-in-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here is an example from a simple Restaurant app.
As you can see the Restaurant object is a property inside the DetailModel. Once i set it inside the OnGet() method. I am able to access its data inside my Razor Page View.

```
public class DetailModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IRestaurantData restaurantData;

    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

    public DetailModel(IRestaurantData restaurantData)
    {
        this.restaurantData = restaurantData;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int restaurantId)
    {
        Restaurant = restaurantData.GetById(restaurantId);
        if(Restaurant == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./NotFound");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

and the view from the page.

```
@page "{restaurantId:int}"

@model MyProject.Pages.Restaurants.DetailModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Detail";
}

<h2>@Model.Restaurant.Name</h2>
<div>
    Id: @Model.Restaurant.Id
</div>
<div>
    Location: @Model.Restaurant.Location
</div>
<div>
    Cuisine: @Model.Restaurant.Cuisine
</div>

@if(Model.Message != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">@Model.Message</div>
}

<a asp-page="./List" class="btn btn-default">All Restaurants</a>
```

Really Razor pages work as one so you do not have to return the Model. You just bind it and you have access inside the page.

Does this makes sense?
Please also read the DOCS for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The Page i want to return has no PageModel.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example. This does not make sense.
In order to have a razor page you need a class that derives from PageModel. 
You are trying to return a complex object correct? Am I missing sth?

Comment: If you want to have the same functionality as MVC, your ASP.NET Core can use the MVC pattern instead.

Comment: Well I do not think you can do it like you want. Razor pages are not built like this. Also why do you need it like this?

Comment: One more comment you can see how the Default  ASP.NET Web Api routes are set. Which is very close to the set up of Razor page but use the MVC pattern.