# How do I post to Razor Page with model - .netcore 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to do a simple post to a .netcore 3.0 Razor page with some model data. I want to get the data while in the first page - then send that to a generic page to show the modal data on another page.

Normally I would do with in a Controller in MVC and return a View while passing in the model.

This is what I am doing (RedirectToPage) which is doing a GET (not POST). I want to post the data.

Index Page

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-1">Test</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Something">Get Lookup Table Data</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

IndexModel

```
public IActionResult OnPostSomething()
{
    var result = _service.GetTableData($"{id}").Result;

    Objresult rr = new Objresult();
    rr.Title = "Get Lookup Tables";
    rr.Request = "";
    rr.Json = result;

    return RedirectToPage("Results","OnPost", rr);

}


 https://localhost:44302/Results?Title=Test&Request=&Json=&handler=OnPost
```

Comment: HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST. When you redirect somewhere, the HTTP "Location" header tells the browser where to go, and the browser makes a GET request for that page. What's your OnPost handler in ResultsModel ? Did you want to get the data in the post request of Index and redirect to the Get method of the Results page  and show the data ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207419/how-do-return-page-with-a-model-in-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 0):

I now realized the Razor Pages are no supposed to work this way. Lesson Learned.

The proper way for me to do what I want in this case would be to create a WebApi for the for my data and then call it in the Razor Pages.

Comment: It's not Razor Pages, the HTTP Protocol doesn't support Post Redirects.