# Passing An Object When A Razor Page Called in asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

So , I'm new to asp.net core 3.1

I Made A Page To Show An Article That Must Grab a `int` parameter Named `postId` and i want to use my repository to get the page with the id given in url `(postId)`

So I Have 3 Questions :

1- How To Define A Route To My Razor Page To Get The `postId` value?

2- I Have The Article Model in My DomainClasses Layer ( it Includes the `title` , `content` , `pageVisits` and etc... ) If I Want To Send My Page A New Instance Of This What I Must Do?

3- I Want To Send My Page A Model Called `PageToShow` ( a new Instance Of Article With Info's Inside)
I Must Initialize This Object In `OnGet` Method Or I Must Create A New Class?

I Seen [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772632/how-pass-objects-from-one-page-to-another-on-asp-net-core-with-razor-pages) Link But It Won't Help Me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- How To Define A Route To My Razor Page To Get The postId value?

You can pass the `postId` to page A by setting `asp-page` and parameter `asp-route-postId`.

In page A, you can directly receive the postId parameter in the `OnGet` method.

> 2- I Have The Article Model in My DomainClasses Layer ( it Includes the title , content , pageVisits and etc... ) If I Want To Send My Page A New Instance Of This What I Must Do?

First define `a BindProperty Article field` in A Page, pass the new entity class, you can trigger the post method, then the Article field will receive your new entity class by using `asp-for` to bind each field.

> 3- I Want To Send My Page A Model Called PageToShow ( a new Instance Of Article With Info's Inside) I Must Initialize This Object In OnGet Method Or I Must Create A New Class?

This is the same as the second question.

---

Below I use two pages to make a simple demo.

The first page `ArticleDatas` is used to display all Article model data, and each line of their data has a link that show details and passing the `postId` to another page `A` .

Page A is to display the data corresponding to the current postId, then modify the data submit button to save the latest data, and then return to the ArticleDatas page.

ArticleDatas.cshtml.cs:

```
public class ArticleDatasModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        [BindProperty]
        public List<Article>  Articles { get; set; }

        public ArticleDatasModel(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Articles = _context.Article.ToList();
        }
    }
```

ArticleDatas.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_core_razorpage.Pages.ArticleDatasModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ArticleDatas";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>ArticleDatas</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.title</td>
            <td><a asp-page="./A" asp-route-postId="@item.Id">Show Details</a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

A.cshtml.cs:

```
public class AModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly MyDbContext _context;
        [BindProperty]
        public Article article { get; set; }
        public AModel(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet(int postId)
        {
            article = _context.Article.Find(postId);
        }


        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            Article articleNew = _context.Article.Find(article.Id);
            articleNew.title = article.title;
            articleNew.content = article.content;
            articleNew.pageVisits = article.pageVisits;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("ArticleDatas");
        }
    }
```

A.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_core_razorpage.Pages.AModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "A";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>A</h1>

    <form asp-action="post">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>content</th>
                <th>pageVisits</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.article.Id" hidden />@Model.article.Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.article.title" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.article.content" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.article.pageVisits" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank U , That Was Really Usefull and solved my problem :)